# I need some way to get true or false if the row contents of two simple one column tables are the same.

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in a SQL Server Stored Procedure:

```
select * from #tbl

select * from @Answers

1   0
2   1
3   0
4   0
5   0

1   0
1   0
1   1
1   1
1   0

CREATE TABLE #tbl (
        [Id]         INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        [Correct]    BIT     
)

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[AnswerList] AS TABLE (
    [Id]       INT NULL,
    [Response] BIT NULL);
```

How can I compare the contents of these tables and come up with a return code of true or false to show if the Id.Correct matches with the Id.Reponse for each row.

Note that the tables will always have the same number of rows and there will be no null values so no need to check for that.

Also note that I just need one output to show if all the rows match or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF Exists (Select t.id
           From #tbl as t
           Left Join @Answers a on t.id = a.id
           Where a.id is null or a.Response <> t.Correct) Begin
    Print 'False'
End Else Begin
    Print 'True'
End
```

Comment: This does not work and also it produces another table. What I need is just the one output saying true or false to show if they all match.

Comment: @Medhi - I tried with same and different rows. Both cases returned False. Could this also just be an inner join without a null check as the tables always have an equal number of rows.